# reactjs function can't use response now that I changed to arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pretty simple function that I'm calling in a react.js app that is querying a table on pouchDB and getting the largest value. This was working previously, but it wasn't allowing me to use `setState` so I changed to arrow function and now inside my `then` block it tells me it can't get `rows` of undefined, undefined referring to `response`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get this to get `response.rows` again and setState for my largestActivities value?

```
queryLargest = () => {
    console.log('good');
    function map(doc, emit) {
        emit(doc._id, doc.activityLogged);
    }
    function reduce(keys, values, rereduce) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
    }
    this.state.activitysDB.db.query({
        map: map, 
        reduce: reduce
    }).then((err, response) => {
        console.log('largest is ' + response.rows[0].value);
        this.setState({
            largestActivity: response.rows[0].value,
        });
        console.log(this.state.largestActivity);
    }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.query` returns a standard Promise, its `.then` will take only one argument, not two - the `(error, result) => {` syntax is what callbacks use, not Promises. When Promises run into an error, they *reject*, which is then handled in a `catch` block, not in the `then` block (usually).

Use

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log('largest is ' + response.rows[0].value);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did allow me to use setState.....however, I'm confused: I can dump my largestActivity from state now and it has the proper value but when I do this: 
```render() {
        const {largestActivity} = this.state;

        return (
        <div>
            <CardComponent 
                items={[
                    this.renderStat('Active Time', {largestActivity}),
                ]}
            />```
it tells me objects are not valid as a react child. So if my ```largestActivity``` is in state and has a valid value, why can't I use it in this component?

Comment: Not sure what `CardComponent` or `renderStat` is, but did you mean to pass a *string* to `renderStat`? `('Active Time', {largestActivity})` will pass a string and an object, did you mean `('Active Time', largestActivity)`

Comment: I guess that would make sense because largestActivity is just a number currently